# Code Blocks GNU GCC cannot find include file

Tags: gcc, codeblocks

Using the GNU GCC compiler I get the error:

```
fatal error: stats.h: No such file or directory.
```

stats.h is a header file I created for the project but for whatever reason it is not being found? I have #include "stats.h" where necessary and I am very confused. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add folder containing stats.h to compiler search directories list

Project | Build options | Search Directories | Compiler

[image]